# Visual Studio 2015 Reporting Services project: create a chart

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, charts

I have created a new "Reporting Services" type project in Visual Studio 2015.

I would like to know how to add a chart to a report, or simply create a SSRS chart in Visual Studio.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I asume you have downloaded SSDT November 2015 Preview for Visual Studio 2015 as detailed here otherwise it won't be available.... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have installed the latest SSDT, that include the "Reporting Services" project template. But I don't see any possibility to make a chart.

Comment: This looks like it might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255273.aspx

Comment: Drag a CHART widget from the toolbox to your report design surface and start setting properties to control it.